# JAVASCRIPT HTML no output

Tags: javascript, html, output

So here is my code and I dont know where is wrong part and the output just dont seem to find its way out. Even my lecturer and friends gave up thinking for me. I read it somewhere maybe it is because of the browser that we used.

```js
<html>
  <head>

  <script type = "text/javascript">

  function calc() {
    var fno1 = parseInt(document.form1.number1.value);
    var fno2 = parseInt(document.form1.number2.value);
    var foperator = parseInt(document.form1.operator.value);
    var msg;

    if (foperator == "1") {
      msg = fno1 + fno2;
    } else if (foperator == "2") {
      msg = fno1 - fno2;
    } else if (foperator == "3") {
      msg = fno1 * fno2;
    } else {
      msg = fno1 / fno2;
    }
    document.form1.result.value = msg;


  }

</script>

</head>

<body

  <form name = "form1"
method = "post"
action = "">
  <table border = "0"
align = "center">

  <tr>
  <td colspan = "4">
  Simple Arithmetic Process </td>
</tr>

  <tr> <td> </td></tr>
  <tr> <td> </td></tr>
  <tr> <td> </td></tr>

  <tr>
  <td> <input name = "number1"
type = "text"
size = "5">

  <td> <select name = "operator">
  <option value = "1"> Add </option>
 <option value="2">Minus</option>
  <option value = "3"> Multiply </option>
 <option value="4">Division</option>
  </td>

<td><input name="number2" type="text" size="5">

<td><input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="calc()">

<td><input name="result" type="text" size="5">
</tr>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, I see you comparing an integer to a string... that's probably not what you want. `foperator == "1"`.

Comment: Your `body` tag is missing an ending `>`. Also, shouldn't put spaces in your element tags. Do this `<head>` not this `< head >`.

Comment: == doesnt type check === does

Comment: Where to start? The HTML is horrendously malformed, as well as poorly laid out for legibility. I worry that your lecturer couldn't find a problem here.. You would greatly benefit from writing your code in an IDE

Comment: also you miss a closing </form> and </select>

Comment: thank you!! you guys point out the mistake.

Comment: Assalamu alaykum wa-rahmutAllah wa-barakatuhu, looks like you've got a few unclosed tags. You don't need so many spaced inside them or around  them, and indentation would help to make this more readable.

Comment: Review valid HTML syntax and correct the HTML rendering issues on this page. After that, I suggest starting with a very simple "calc()" JavaScript function with two lines: 1) alert("calc function start");  and 2) alert("calc function end");. Add new JavaScript lines between these two alert statements. Once the calc function works correctly, comment out the alert statements.

Comment: @Pureferret wassalam. i saw that. thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @JohnH great tip! thank you!

Comment: I shouldn't have edited that question. I fixed the spaces in the HTML tags which allowed the page to render, despite the broken `<body` tag (I tried it in Firefox), but the JS didn't work anyway. However this broken formatting was part of the original question, and that's the way the OP tried to run it. I wanted to cancel my edit when I realized it, but there is no "cancel edit" feature here on SO. And the edit finally got approved... Dear OP, don't write HTML tags with spaces like this `< table >`, instead write it without spaces `<table>` or spaces before the args only: `<table border="0">`